# Interpretation of an integral of a function $f$

Tags: integration, functions, notation

When we think of a Riemann integral, it is usually defined as $\lim_{\Delta x_{k}\rightarrow 0}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}f(x_{k}^{*})\Delta x_{k} = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)~dx$. This means that $f(x)$ should be interpreted as the value of $f$ at $x$, since we are multiplying function values by "infinitesimal intervals." Therefore, how is integration an operation on functions, when the integrand is not a function but the output of a function at $x$?

Comment: $f(x)$ is indeed the value of $f$ at $x$. Did you mean to say integral? Your interpretation is incorrect then.

Comment: @voldemort I'm not sure what you are trying to say. My question is, why is the operation of integration considered to be one on functions (i.e., $f: x \mapsto f(x)$) when the integrand, which is the input in the operation of integration, is not a function but a real number $f(x)$.

Comment: This is a misconception on your part. The input is indeed a function. "$x$ varies over $[a,b]$". A better notation for integration is to just write it as $\int_{[a,b]}f dx$, without refernce to $x$.

Comment: @voldemort If that is the case, then why is it necessary to have some formula for $f(x)$ in order to calculate an integral?

Comment: Miles: I don't think I follow your question very well. I shall let some one more experienced handle your doubts.

Comment: Integrals are nothing more than a sum of all of the "$dx$'s" along $f$. $f\left(x\right)$ is the value of $f$ at some $x$, and the $dx$ is like adding a little bit, making the summation a viable definition of an integral in discrete form instead of infinitesimal form. However, a $dx$ is of course nothing more than an infinitesimal step along $f$, but it must be at a value of $f\left(x\right)$.